# Unclosed tag on line 6: 'with'. Looking for one of: endwith

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm learning how to use Django Templates but im getting this error

```
Unclosed tag on line 6: 'with'. Looking for one of: endwith.
```

this is my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Favorite rapper:</h1>

    {% with person="2pac" %}

    <h1>{{person}}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

[this is the tutorial that I'm doing](https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_template_variables.php)

Comment: Here is an example from your textbook https://www.w3schools.com/django/ref_tags_with.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error makes complete sense you should close the `with` tag so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Favorite rapper:</h1>

    {% with person="2pac" %}

    <h1>{{person}}</h1>
    {% endwith %}
  </body>
</html>
```